# Current process handle strange macros

Tags: c++, c, windows

There is a windows runtime macros [ZwCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566431(v=vs.85).aspx) (NtCurrentProcess for user mode) that returns handle to the current process.
It defined in wdm.h and looks like

```
#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )  
#define ZwCurrentProcess() NtCurrentProcess()
```

What is the meaning of ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )? How can it gets current process handle?

Comment: It's not a function call, that "pseudo-function" will be replaced with a constant because "-1" (=all bits set) is a magic number to denote current process...every function that accepts an handle to a process will "understand" that.

Comment: So this magic value is allways the same. Then how to save it's value and use it in second process, to pass  first process handle as argument?

Comment: Yes it'll be. I suppose it's an optimization for all the functions that need an handle to current process. You can't pass that handle to another process simply because an handle isn't valid outside process where you obtained it. You have to use PID you get with `GetCurrentProcessId()`. From that ID the other process can obtain an handle with `OpenProcess()`.

Comment: ok i got it! thatnks. in kernel in it not the same because i can get handle on current process with ZwOpenProcess and it will be valid anywere in kernel.Closed

Comment: Use `DuplicateHandle` to convert the pseudo handle to a real handle. Also, you should be using `GetCurrentProcess`.